# getting Request.Form.Files always empty in asp.net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to upload a file in asp.net core web api. For that i have one web app which is calling my web api.

Here is the web app code in which i am attaching the file

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Sample");

    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        var fileContent2 = new StreamContent(firmwareImage.InputStream);
        fileContent2.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = firmwareImage.FileName
        };
        content.Add(fileContent2);

        var result = await client.PostAsync(serviceUrl, content);
        var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

and here is the screenshot of that attched content while debugging. Sorry for the blurry image in debug value portion.

[image]

now in web api i am receiving this request by

```
 var files = Request.Form.Files;
```

but i am getting empty files always. Count is always zero. Here is the screenshot of same request.
[image]

what i am doing wrong and why i am not getting attached file in web api?

Comment: Have you tried setting the content type header as multipart/form-data?

Comment: yes but that code was not able to work for me. so i have changed the api request code with multipart/form-data. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to post an image from above code so i have tried below code and it works fine.

```
 HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
 MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();

 FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead("your file path");
 var streamContent = new StreamContent(fs);

 var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(streamContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);
 imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");

 form.Add(imageContent, "image", Path.GetFileName("your file name"));
 var response = httpClient.PostAsync("apiurl", form).Result;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing `enctype = "multipart/form-data"`. you need this on your mvc form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                    <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
                    <button type="submit" >  
            }
```